# Calling another overloaded method in Lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, clos

I couldn't find out if this was possible, and just used a (rather ugly) workaround.

Assume we've got a class structure as below:

```
(defclass a () ())
(defclass b (a) ())
```

and the method:

```
(defmethod print-object ((a1 a) stream)
 (format stream "instance of A "))
```

now, I want to call print for 'a then print for 'b, assuming a "type-cast" function exists:

```
(defmethod print-object ((b1 b) stream)
 (prin1 (type-cast b1 'a) stream)
 (format stream "instance of B "))
```

My workaround is to create an object of type a within print-object of b, then call prin1

```
(defmethod print-object ((b1 b) stream)
 (let ((a1 (make-instance 'a)))
    (prin1 a1 stream))
 (format stream "instance of B "))
```

I tried coerce and ended up with infinite loop. I just realized I can try using find-method and call-method (would it work?). Or should I try a solution with :around?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`COERCE` does not work with CLOS objects. You can change the class of an instance with `CHANGE-CLASS`, but that's usually not a good idea.

**`CALL-NEXT-METHOD`**

You can call the next applicable method: `CALL-NEXT-METHOD`. Note that you can't call a specific method that way, just the next one. Most of the time this is what one would use in CLOS. The task is then during method definition to set up the generic function in such a way, using primary, `:around`, `:before` and `:after` methods, that the right behavior emerges.

**Calling specific functions when all else fails**

There is an esoteric way to call a specific method:

```
(funcall (method-function (find-method #'print-object
                                       nil
                                       (list (find-class 'a)
                                             (find-class t))))
         (make-instance 'b)
         t)
```

In above code, the function `METHOD-FUNCTION` is not part of ANSI Common Lisp, but provided in many implementations by the [Metaobject Protocol (MOP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaobject#Metaobject_protocol).

Answer (score 6):

`Coerce` doesn't create new object because b1 is already has type (subtype) of `a` already.

All you need is `call-next-method`:

```
(defmethod print-object ((a1 a) stream)
   (format stream "instance of A "))

(defmethod print-object ((b1 b) stream)
   (call-next-method) ; by default same arguments are used: b1 and stream
   (format stream "instance of B "))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, monoid. I'll accept Rainer's answer as he explains that it's not enough by itself (if we have a more realistic class hierarchy) to call-next-method but we need to use it in conjunction with :around, :before and :after. I need to study these concepts a bit more now :)

Answer (score 0):

Following the example on process locks by Sonya Keene (Object-Oriented Programming in COMMON LISP: A Programmer's Guide to CLOS), you can use an :after method

```
(defmethod print-object ((a1 a) stream)
  (format stream "instance of A ")) 
(defmethod print-object :after ((b1 b) stream)
  (format stream "instance of B "))
```

This will give

```
CL-USER> (make-instance 'b)
    instance of A instance of B
```