# Invoking print-object on a list of symbols

Tags: common-lisp

I have a global list of symbols, CLOS objects, and a corresponding `print-object` method defined that gives them succinct summaries. I'd like to provide the user with a `show-all` method that loops over them and prints the same output that I get at the REPL, using `print-object`. An [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20778267/calling-another-overloaded-method-in-lisp) suggested `method-function` to look up the specific method and then `funcall` it, but using `closer-mop` isn't an option.

I can get a specific object to print in the loop, but not looping over the list, e.g.:

```lisp
(defun show-all (&optional (stream *standard-output*))
  "Print summaries for all objects in the current environment"
  (dolist (o *master-list*)
    (format t "~A~%" o) ; prints symbol name as text
    (print-object foo::my-object *standard-output*) ;prints my-object using print-object, this is what I want
    (print-object o *standard-output*))) ; same as format, prints symbol-name as text
```

Anyone have any ideas of what's going on here? If I can print a specific object in the environment using `print-object`, I should be able to print all of them looping over the list of symbols.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A symbol is not the same as a thing that it names.

Since `print-object` is a (generic) function, normal evaluation applies.  It gets the *value* of `foo::my-object` as an argument.  It never sees the symbol `foo::my-object`.  If you iterate over a list of symbols, you still need to lookup whatever values you want, e. g. using `symbol-value` if they name global values.

You have specialized your `print-object` method on some class, right?  Not on an eql specializer for each symbol?

Comment: Correct. Lesson here: don't program late at night no matter the deadline. Or at least wait overnight before asking questions.